# Would it be possible to change the parent of an instanced object in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, instance, parent

Would it be possible to change the parent of an instanced object in unity?

Generally my thought is that it would be just the same as any other GameObject.

```
myObject.transform.SetParent(newParentObject.transform);
```

But I thought there may be special rules for cloned objects because you set the parent in creation of the instance object. Do they have rules (what are they) or is it the same?

Comment: Did you try that code? Does it work or not? Let us know if there is a problem with that.

Comment: I haven't yet, I am away from my computer right now. If no one knows, I'll try it when I can get back and post an answer.

Comment: I suggest you do that. If you don't mind, what do you mean by instaced object which is in the title?

Comment: @Programmer    https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. It is the same code. (Just asked an old friend) so if someone needs to know:

```
myObject.transform.SetParent(newParentObject.transform);
```